# Data not populating on update trigger

Tags: trigger

I have a update trigger which retrieve aggregate results from a object. They need to be populated in another object (Funding_Cycles_TA__c). There is no run time errors or compile errors. but data is not populating as i wanted. My code is

```
trigger PopulateFCTAFromTP on Training_Plan__c (after update) {

    Set<Id> TAIds = new Set<Id>();
    // List< Training_Agreement__c> tasForUpdate = new List<Training_Agreement__c>();
      List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c> FCTAToUpdate = new List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c>();
    Training_Plan__c[] TPs = null;

    if(Trigger.isInsert||Trigger.isUpdate){
        TPs = Trigger.new;
    }else if(Trigger.isDelete){
        TPs = Trigger.old;
    }
    //select the Training plans
    for (Training_Plan__c TP : TPs) {
        if((TP.Training_Agreement__c != null) 
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Active') 
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Grace')
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Complete')
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='On Hold') 
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Withdrawn')
           ||(TP.TEC_Status__c=='Pending Transfer')){
               TAIds.add(TP.Training_Agreement__c);
           }
    }
     system.debug('TESTTEST') ;

    //Aggregate SOQL from Funding_Cycles_TPS__c
    List<AggregateResult> agrResults =
        [SELECT 
         Reporting_Year__c reportingYear,
         sum(Achieved_Credits_Total__c) achievedCredits, 
         sum(Funded_Achieved_Credits__c) fundedCredits, 
         Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c ita
         FROM Funding_Cycles_TPS__c
         WHERE Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c in :TAIds 
         //where  Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c = 'a0w0M00000VpgtI' 
         GROUP BY Reporting_Year__c, Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c
         Order BY Reporting_Year__c];
     //system.debug('TESTTEST' + count(id)) ;

    //Corrosponding Funding_Cycles_TA__c(Child records)need to be updated from Training Agreement
    List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c>  fctasToUpdate = [Select id,Reporting_Year__c,
                                                 Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c,
                                                 Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c,
                                                 Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c
                                                 From Funding_Cycles_TA__c
                                                 where Training_Agreement__c in: TAIds order by Reporting_Year__c ];

    /*  for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults) 
    {fctasToUpdate.add(new Funding_Cycles_TA__c(Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c = (Decimal)ar.get('fundedCredits'), 
          Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c = (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits')));  }  */


    for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults)
    {
         for(Funding_Cycles_TA__c eachFCTA : fctasToUpdate)
        {
                system.debug('TCTA ID ' +eachfcta.id);
                system.debug('aggregate year        ' +(Date)ar.get('reportingYear'));
                system.debug('reportingYear of fcta ' +eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c );
            if(eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c == (Date)ar.get('reportingYear')
               && eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c != Null)
             //  && eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c!=Null 
             //  && eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c !=NULL)
                system.debug('FCTA ID ' +eachfcta.id);
            {
                eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c = (Decimal)ar.get('fundedCredits');
                eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c = (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits');
                eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c = eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c + (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits');
                 system.debug('Agr Total  ' + (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits'));
                 system.debug('fcta Total ' + eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!fctasToUpdate.isEmpty()){
      update fctasToUpdate; } 
}
```

Comment: best way, to fix the trigger is to write test class and run with sample data

Answer (score 0):

EachFCTA is the temp variable to the loop there is no change in the fctasToUpdate list that portion is commented. Try to use a new List to update data.

Comment: I added a new list just before the loop now I get duplicate id in list error

Comment: List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c> FCTAToUpdate1 = new List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c>();

Comment: I added this list before the loop. Now I get duplicate ID error.

Comment: You got duplicate because you were looping through FCTAToUpdate and might be adding it back to FCTAToUpdate list itself.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `fctasToUpdate` has no meaning in your code. Also `eachFCTA` is temp variable that you use to loop through `fctasToUpdate`. You would need a new list `List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c> NewfctasToUpdateList = new List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c>();` that would contain objects of type `Funding_Cycles_TA__c` i.e. `eachFCTA`, with its fields populated with appropriate aggregated values. This is what you need to change:

```
 //Corrosponding Funding_Cycles_TA__c(Child records)need to be updated from Training Agreement
            List < Funding_Cycles_TA__c > fctasToUpdate = [Select id, Reporting_Year__c,
             Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c,
             Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c,
             Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c
             From Funding_Cycles_TA__c
             where Training_Agreement__c in : TAIds order by Reporting_Year__c
            ];

            /*  for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults) 
            {fctasToUpdate.add(new Funding_Cycles_TA__c(Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c = (Decimal)ar.get('fundedCredits'), 
                  Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c = (Decimal)ar.get('achievedCredits')));  }  */
            // This list will be used to update the Funding_Cycles_TA__c record fields
            List < Funding_Cycles_TA__c > NewfctasToUpdateList = new List < Funding_Cycles_TA__c > ();

            for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults) {
             for (Funding_Cycles_TA__c eachFCTA: fctasToUpdate) {
              system.debug('TCTA ID ' + eachfcta.id);
              system.debug('aggregate year        ' + (Date) ar.get('reportingYear'));
              system.debug('reportingYear of fcta ' + eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c);
              if (eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c == (Date) ar.get('reportingYear') && eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c != Null)
              //  && eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c!=Null 
              //  && eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c !=NULL)
               system.debug('FCTA ID ' + eachfcta.id); {

               eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c = (Decimal) ar.get('fundedCredits');
               eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c = (Decimal) ar.get('achievedCredits');
               eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c = eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c + (Decimal) ar.get('achievedCredits');
               NewfctasToUpdateList.add(eachFCTA); // add the record to new list to update
               system.debug('Agr Total  ' + (Decimal) ar.get('achievedCredits'));
               system.debug('fcta Total ' + eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c);
              }
             }
            }
            if (!NewfctasToUpdateList.isEmpty()) {
             update NewfctasToUpdateList;
            }
```

**Update** - You have a flaw in the logic that is why your list is getting duplicates. You are looping through `fctasToUpdate` again and again inside the loop of `AggregateResult`. What you need is a `Map` to avoid this multiple looping. Create a Map like below:

```
 //Aggregate SOQL from Funding_Cycles_TPS__c
    List<AggregateResult> agrResults =
        [SELECT 
         Reporting_Year__c reportingYear,
         sum(Achieved_Credits_Total__c) achievedCredits, 
         sum(Funded_Achieved_Credits__c) fundedCredits, 
         Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c ita
         FROM Funding_Cycles_TPS__c
         WHERE Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c in :TAIds 
         //where  Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c = 'a0w0M00000VpgtI' 
         GROUP BY Reporting_Year__c, Training_Plan_Standard__r.Training_Plan__r.Training_Agreement__c
         Order BY Reporting_Year__c];


    Map<Id,AggregateResult> aggregatedMap = new Map<Id,AggregateResult>();
    For(AggregateResult ar : agrResults){

    // aggregatedMap.put('key',ar); // use a Key which is available in fctasToUpdate List. Example if you can get the Id of Funding_Cycles_TA__c in your above query use that here or use anyfield which is common between `Funding_Cycles_TA__c` and `Funding_Cycles_TPS__c`

    }
```

Once you have the map , you can use it in the for loop to get the corespoding aggregate value for each `Funding_Cycles_TA__c` record in `fctasToUpdate`.

```
        List < Funding_Cycles_TA__c > NewfctasToUpdateList = new List < Funding_Cycles_TA__c > ();

         for (Funding_Cycles_TA__c eachFCTA: fctasToUpdate) {
          system.debug('TCTA ID ' + eachfcta.id);

          if (eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c == (Date) ar.get('reportingYear') && eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c != Null)

           system.debug('FCTA ID ' + eachfcta.id); {

           eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Funded__c =  (Decimal)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('fundedCredits'); // Use the appropiate key that you decide.For example here I used eachFCTA.id 
           eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c = (Decimal)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('achievedCredits');
           eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c = eachFCTA.Achieved_Credits_in_Rpting_Yr_Total__c + (Decimal)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('achievedCredits');

           NewfctasToUpdateList.add(eachFCTA); // add the record to new list to update

          }
         }

        if (!NewfctasToUpdateList.isEmpty()) {
         update NewfctasToUpdateList;
        }
```

Comment: it throws an error 'System.ListException: Duplicate id in list'. instead list I tried with set. but i got same error.

Comment: Your statement looks incorrect - "instead list I tried with set. but i got same error". First of all you cannot use update with a Set. Second, Set can never have duplicates. I recommend you go through the Set - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm

Comment: Check my update now. You were looping through fctasToUpdate list multiple times because of outer for loop for AggregateResult. Consider using a Map for this. I did not compile this but it should work fine.

Comment: I updated the trigger and used Training_Agreement__id as the 'Key' as it is common id. But it didn't work as compile error was thrown. so I used Date field as the 'Key' as Reporting_Year__c. But Now I get NULL pointer in run time error as System.NullPointerException : Attempt to de-reference a null object: but I addressed all posible NULL values in the loop. But the test record I am running , there is no NULL vales for any fields

Comment: Remember Map's key should be unique else when you put another value with the same key it will override the existing value in the Map. Paste what you tried in the question that may be helpful to debug.

Comment: Map<String,AggregateResult> aggregatedMap = new Map<String,AggregateResult>();
    For(AggregateResult ar : agrResults){
        
        aggregatedMap.put('reportingYear',ar); }
    If statement: If((Date)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('reportingYear') !=NULL && eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c != Null &&
           (Decimal)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('fundedCredits')!= NULL && (Decimal)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('achievedCredits') !=NULL){
               if(eachFCTA.Reporting_Year__c == (Date)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('reportingYear'))

Comment: If my trigger is complex then try as a sample assuming Parent A has two child objects B and C, having Reporting_Year__c as the common field in both child objects. What I need some filed values in Child B object to be updated on Child C object with corresponding Reporting_Year__c. The number of records in Child object B is less than that of Child C. Object C is child of Object D. we need the update process happens when update on object D.   The relationship ( A->D->C ) and ( A->B). I think this simplify the trigger. Thanks

Comment: Your syntax does not make sense. You created a Map with Date as the key of it - `Map<String,AggregateResult> aggregatedMap = new Map<String,AggregateResult>(); For(AggregateResult ar : agrResults){ aggregatedMap.put('reportingYear',ar); }`( it should be ar.get('reportingYear') by the way) and you are using 'id' field as the key to retrieve the data - `(Date)aggregatedMap.get(eachFCTA.id).get('reportingYear')` . This is not correct and will obviously throw an error.